# Как проверить observable на не null

Tags: java, android, rest, rxjava

```
api.getActiveSimpleOrder(rest_id) 
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                  ****  .flatMap( result-> { if(result!=null) Observable::from;}) ******
                    .flatMap(offer -> api.getStatus(offer.getId()) // запрашиваем статус
                            .doOnNext(offer::setStatus) // записываем полученный статус в объект заказа
                            .map(status -> offer) // небольшая хитрость что бы дальше шли объекты заказов а не статусов
                    )
                    .toList() // преобразуем последовательность обратно в список
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())// дальнейшие действия над данными будем производить в главном потоке
                    .subscribe(offers::addAll,
                            Exception -> Toast.makeText(
                                    getApplicationContext(), (CharSequence) Exception, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).
                                    show(),
                            () -> {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        getApplicationContext(), "Data Receive Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).
                                        show();
                                sortOffers(offers);
                            });
```

api.getActiveSimpleOrder(rest_id) возвращает List который может быть равен null Либо нет, если он не пустой то все работает. но если пустой то строка *** **** возвращает эксепшн который не ловится даже с помощью try catch, может быть из за асинхронности,

Вопрос в следующем: как алгоритму дать понять что если пришедший обсервабл равен null то ничего из того что написано в коде делать не надо?

Comment: а `filter( r -> r != null )` вам не подходит?

Answer (score 1):

Это не является полным ответом на вопрос, однако решает проблему с ошибкой при отработке данного куска кода,

При получении пустого листа (null) в Observable вызывается метод OnError, и программа выполняется дальше, ошибка была в теле метода OnError а именно в строке

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (CharSequence) Exception, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(),
```

а именно (CharSequence) Exception, где имя класса было и именем переменной, поэтому ее было так тяжело увидеть и отловить, потому что все указывало на OnError однако дело было не в Observable а в теле метода.

Так же стоит добавить что в случае если пришедший Observable - null> вызываетмя метод OnComplete сразу. 
Так же стоит отметить что существует Onservable.empty() тип данных не порождающий ничего и заверщающий свое выполнение.
На этом у меня все